# Error when read parquet file use Parquet Modular Encryption

Tags: java, apache-spark, parquet

I try write parquet file use Parquet Modular Encryption
https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Encryption.md
I use spark java to write file with code:

```
sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.crypto.factory.class",
                "org.apache.parquet.crypto.keytools.PropertiesDrivenCryptoFactory");

        sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.encryption.key.material.store.internally", "false");

        sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.encryption.kms.client.class",
                "org.apache.parquet.crypto.keytools.mocks.InMemoryKMS");
        // Explicit master keys (base64 encoded) - required only for mock InMemoryKMS
        sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.encryption.key.list",
                "keyA:AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==,keyB:AAECAAECAAECAAECAAECAA==,keyC:AAECAwPFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==,keyD:AAECAwPFdgcICQoLDA0ODw==");

        String csvPath = "/home/tuantq2/Downloads/stat/perstat/stats_data_read_csv9.csv";

        Dataset<Row> csvData = sc.read()
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", "true") // Nếu có header trong file CSV
                .option("inferSchema", "true") // Tự động suy đoán kiểu dữ liệu của cột
                .load(csvPath);
        csvData.show();
        csvData.write().
                option("parquet.encryption.column.keys", "keyA:team").
                option("parquet.encryption.footer.key", "keyB").
                //                option("parquet.encryption.column.keys", "keyC:path").
                mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).
                parquet("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/data/tuantq2/parquet_sec/teampath.parquet.encrypted");
```

then when I try read:

```
sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.encryption.key.material.store.internally",
                "false");

        sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.crypto.factory.class",
                "org.apache.parquet.crypto.keytools.PropertiesDrivenCryptoFactory");

        sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.encryption.kms.client.class",
                "org.apache.parquet.crypto.keytools.mocks.InMemoryKMS");
        // Explicit master keys (base64 encoded) - required only for mock InMemoryKMS
        sc.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("parquet.encryption.key.list",
                "keyA:AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==,keyB:AAECAAECAAECAAECAAECAA==,keyC:AAECAwPFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==,keyD:AAECAwPFdgcICQoLDA0ODw==");

        Dataset<Row> df = sc.read()
                .parquet("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000//data/tuantq2/parquet_sec/teampath.parquet.encrypted/").select("team");
        df.show();
```

I receved error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.parmap(ThreadUtils.scala:375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.readParquetFootersInParallel(ParquetFileFormat.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$1$adapted(ParquetFileFormat.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaMergeUtils$.$anonfun$mergeSchemasInParallel$2(SchemaMergeUtils.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2(RDD.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitions$2$adapted(RDD.scala:863)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for file: FileStatus{path=hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/data/tuantq2/parquet_sec_vault/teampath.parquet.encrypted/part-00000-30a08af7-5f92-4ae8-88c0-e1c327b0060d-c000.snappy.parquet; isDirectory=false; length=16240; replication=0; blocksize=0; modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=; permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false; hasAcl=false; isEncrypted=false; isErasureCoded=false}
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotReadFooterForFileError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:726)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.$anonfun$parmap$2(ThreadUtils.scala:372)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
    at scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
    at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.parquet.crypto.keytools.FileKeyUnwrapper.getKey(FileKeyUnwrapper.java:87)
    at org.apache.parquet.crypto.InternalFileDecryptor.setFileCryptoMetaData(InternalFileDecryptor.java:187)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:592)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.<init>(ParquetFileReader.java:777)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.open(ParquetFileReader.java:658)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFooterReader.readFooter(ParquetFooterReader.java:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$.$anonfun$readParquetFootersInParallel$1(ParquetFileFormat.scala:467)
    ... 13 more
```

But  when write parquet with parquet.encryption.key.material.store.internally=true then everything's fine
Please help me solve this. Thank all for helps.

when I try write file parquet with option parquet.encryption.key.material.store.internally=true then everything's fine